# (infinite?) loop in javascript code

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following JavaScript code to "display" XML on a website:

```
function createChild(node,tabindex){

    var child = node.childNodes;

    var r = '';

    var tabs = '';

    for(i=0;i<tabindex;i++){

        tabs += "\t";

    };

    for(i=0;i<child.length;i++){

        if(child[i].nodeType == 1){

            r += tabs+"&lt;"+child[i].nodeName+"&gt;\n";

            if(child[i].hasChildNodes()){ r += createChild(child[i],1); }; // here is where it fails!

            r += tabs+"&lt;/"+child[i].nodeName+"&gt;\n";

        }

    }

    return r;

 };


function parseXML(xml){

    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml,'application/xml');

    var node = doc.getElementsByTagName('*')[0];

    var r = '';

    r += "&lt;<span class=\"highlight highlight-blue\">"+node.nodeName+"</span>&gt;\n";

    if(node.hasChildNodes()){ r += createChild(node,1); };

    r += "&lt;<span class=\"highlight highlight-blue\">/"+node.nodeName+"</span>&gt;\n";

    $('.viewer').html(r);
};
```

This works fine on XML like this:

```
<properties>
    <property></property>
</properties>
```

But it fails to work when there is more than one child like this:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <value></value>
    </property>
</properties>
```

The code keeps running until my browser crashes. I **think** there is an infinite loop in it, but I'm not sure. Does anyone have a tip for me?

Comment: "_I **think** there is an infinite loop in it, but I'm not sure_" You can use your debugger and then you will **know**.

Comment: browser crashes when I launch the code. My console is not showing anything.

Comment: So put a breakpoint on the first line of code and stop letting it execute...

Comment: when I remove the following "r += createChild(child[i],1);" and I put in a console.log('text')... I works. So the problem is with the createChild function obviously. But I'm asking this question because I cannot find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is why you should **always** declare your variables:

```
// declare 'i'
for(var i = 0; i < tabindex ; i++){
  tabs += "\t";
};
```

If you don't declare `i` in the function scope, it will be global, thus interfering with the `for` loop in a recursive function call:

1. The `i` variable is set to `0` in the first function call.
2. The function is calls itself.
3. The `i` variable is set to `0`.
4. The function returns.
5. `i` is now `0` again, so the loop in the first frame will run forever.

So somewhere in the `createChild` function, you have to declare `i`, either before the first loop or in the first loop. You can also use `let`.