# Why does this javascript for loop cause an early exit?

Tags: javascript

Right now I am really stumped. I have a short function, called "validate", and for some reason the for loop I have prevents an outer for loop from running.

Here it is breaking by only printing out the first entry:

```
function validate(str) {
    for(i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        // do nothing
    }
    return str;
}
```

And here's the version that works:

```
function validate(str) {
    /*for(i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        // do nothing
    }*/
    return str;
}
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nosefouratyou/32z2gk77/).
Here is the [sample text file](https://gist.github.com/nosefouratyou/14d68142b8af590337ba0f286ca8ead5).

Comment: Try isolating your variable `i`. `var i = 0;`

Comment: post the code in the question, stackoverflow has same functionality as jsfiddle. but my guess is today you learn why `var` is not optional.

Comment: **var i = 0; Always declare variables :/**

Comment: I just answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45488952/5989584).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try encapsulating your variable `i`. `var i = 0;`

```
function validate(str) {
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        // do nothing
    }
    return str;
}
```

Without the `var` you are adding it to the global scope or the `window` object

Comment: Thank you! I am indeed an idiot today. I'll accept your answer shortly (there is a waiting period apparently for accepting an answer).